# I am trying to do summary for a lot of linear models

Tags: r, math

I am trying to do summaries on variables which are just lists of numbers, mats <- c(1,2,3,4,5). However when I run my code it only returns one result instead of iterating through and doing summaries for all the variables against the last one.

```
summary_model <- function(...){
  args = list(...)
  n_args = length(args)
  for (i in 1: (n_args - 1)) {
    return(summary(lm(args[[i]] ~ args[[n_args]])))
  }
}
```

Comment: Return stops the execution of the function.

Comment: Can you share some input values to `summary_model` and show what would you expect as output?

Comment: mats <- (1,2,3,4,5) fins <- (1.1,1.9,2.2,4.1,5.4) djia <- (1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5)   sum_mod(mats,fins,djia)    then we would get  but for mats~djia and fins~djia                                                          
```Call:
lm(formula = mats ~ djia)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.070083 -0.015838 -0.003258  0.018010  0.054780 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)     0.03823    0.01343   2.847   0.0192 *
args[[n_args]]  0.42923    0.16614   2.584   0.0295 *
---